# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement for register

Tags: sql

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=..\VisitorPass.accdb"
        con = New OleDbConnection(str)
        Dim sql As String = "insert into Visitor(Name,Password)values ('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtPassword.Text & "')"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Account is Registered")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: Use `insert into Visitor(Name,Password) values ...`, with a space in between the parenthesis and `values`.

Comment: i tried but the cmd.executenonquery() popup and say Oledbexception was unhandled , Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: and i am using Microsoft Access as my database

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the field password in brackets.

```
insert into Visitor(Name,[Password])values ..
```

This should do the trick when using MS Access.

Comment: thank you for solving my problem. i tried [password] and it is working. may i know that how does [] use for? for example,  password and [password].

Comment: To avoid using special words that sql uses... for example the if you have a field named 'Date' and Date is also a function in SQL so you write [Date] to let him know that you mean the column not the function.

Comment: Interestingly, *Name* is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in MS Access and should be bracketed which would have been my suggestion, not *Password*.